# When using unnumbered theorems, latex fails to compile

Tags: theorems

I'm using the unnumbered theorems in the `amsthm` package as the following:

```
\newtheorem*{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
```

But my file fails to compile. In particular, it says `Latex Error: missing \begin{document}`
which I apparently have because I was able to compile without the asteroid sign after the newtheorem.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type

```
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
```

it means you already have something like

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

(maybe with a different trailing optional argument, or none altogether) and you want that `corollary` shares the numbering with `theorem`.

In the case of unnumbered theorem-like environments, this is meaningless, because the new environment has no number to begin with, so none to share. Hence

```
\newtheorem*{exercise}{Exercise}
```

is what you need.